# Will something accelerate forever if a constant force is applied on a frictionless plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

Will something accelerate forever if a constant force is applied on a frictionless plane, or will it continue to move with constant velocity the moment the applied force is removed?

Comment: why would it not continue to accelerate? this is newtons laws of motion

Comment: As it's a frictionless plane , the $something$ will move with constant velocity as soon as force is removed ...

Comment: @sithuhlaing... Answer it , what will be the work done by you when $something$ moves incessantly ...?

Comment: Infinity, of course. but if only if I keep applying the force, right?

Comment: @sithuhlaing...infinite it is till you apply force up to infinity ... Or else not ...

Comment: This is not an either-or case. Both of your statements are true

Answer (score 3):

It will continue to accelerate for as long as the force is applied. If it is applied forever it will accelerate forever, however if the force ever stops, the object will move at a constant velocity.

Comment: Perhaps change "if it ever stops" to "if the force ever stops" as "it" is potentially ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

**I) Circular motion**

If circular motion is allowed in your question, then, you need to prove, at least, that: the **universe**, it’s **laws** and **mater** (any gravitational source) are **eternal**.

In this framework a moon made up of eternal matter orbiting a planet made up with similar (eternal) stuff, in a perfect circular orbit will be under *constant acceleration* forever.

**II) Linear motion**

In this case you should not only prove that the **universe**, it’s **laws** and **mater** (any gravitational source) are **eternal**, but that it is infinite in **size** and has an infinite net **energy** in it as well, because

Under constant linear acceleration (force)

1. the displacement is $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$, and speed $v=at$, therefore if $t \rightarrow \infty$ then $x \rightarrow \infty; \, v \rightarrow \infty$.
2. the work done is $W=max= \frac{1}{2}m(at)^2$, therefore if $t \rightarrow \infty$ then $W \rightarrow \infty$.

*) $a$: Magnitude of acceleration; $t$: time elapsed; $m$: body mass.

**PS:** This is under Newtonian approach, at some moment relativistic effects are going to be impossible ignored anymore. In this case your infinity will just be the speed of light $c$ and the results will be: $t \rightarrow \infty$ then $x \rightarrow \infty; \, v \rightarrow c; \, W \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about linear motion, NO, it won't. As the speed of the mass keeps on increasing and becomes comparable to the speed of light, the relativistic mass of the particle starts to play a role, $m=\frac{m_o}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ where $m_o$ is the rest mass of the particle. You see once this becomes "$infinite$" (very large) for any further acceleration, either you have to increase the amount of force that you are applying or with the same force and increasing mass the acceleration would keep on decreasing. So once the speed is quite close to the speed of light (say $0.99999c$), you need infinitely large force to further accelerate it; and this is something which is very non physical (at least to me).